# In QML, is there a way to set anchor.bottom on an Item without setting height?

Tags: qt, qml

I'm new to Qt and QML.  Examples I have seen recommend wrapping components with an Item.  I want the thing the item contains to be positioned at the bottom of the application window.  So, I set the item's anchor.bottom to parent.bottom.  This makes the contained thing not show up.  This tiny example shows the issue where the contained 'thing' is a Rectangle.

```
Window {
    width: 800
    height: 500
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Test")

    Item {
        anchors {
            bottom: parent.bottom
        }

        Rectangle {
            width: 80
            height: 80
            color: "#FF0000"
        }
    }
}
```

I realize the item has no explicit height and its implicit height is initially 0.  I believe the item's anchor is applied when the item has no height.  So its bottom is its top.  So its top gets set to the window bottom, effectively locating it below the window.  But, the contained rectangle has a height.  Does the item not dynamically size before the anchor is applied?

Is there a proper way to do this other than just deleting the Item wrapper?  In my actual code, the item is not wrapping a simple rectangle.  It wraps a RowLayout that contains multiple things that are not the same height.  I want the RowLayout to dynamically size its height.

Comment: " I have seen recommend wrapping components with an Item". Where and what was the reasonning? That's not something I would recomment, quite the contrary if it is not needed like in your case.

Comment: "Learn Qt 5" by Nicholas Sherriff is where I first came across it.  But, I've seen it other places as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrapping components in an `Item` is not a general rule that should be followed everywhere. Sometimes it's helpful, but not in this case. Just getting rid of your Item should solve your problem.

```
Window {
    width: 800
    height: 500
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Test")

    Rectangle {
        anchors {
            bottom: parent.bottom
        }

        width: 80
        height: 80
        color: "#FF0000"
    }
}
```

That should also work if your replace the `Rectangle` with a `RowLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is create a parent Item element that fills the whole window, then anchor your item to that.

```
Window {
    width: 800
    height: 500
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Test")

    Item {
        anchors.fill: parent
        width: 100
        height: 100

        Rectangle {
            width: 80
            height: 80
            color: "#FF0000"
            /* anchor to the bottom of item */
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom 
        }
     }
}
```

Why? I'm not quite sure exactly, but it sure seems to work this way.

--

If you wanted to wrap a RowLayout, you would use the same basic technique....

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15
import QtQuick 2.15
 
Window {
    width: 800
    height: 500
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Test")

    Item {
        anchors.fill: parent
        width: 100
        height: 100
        RowLayout {
            id: layout
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            anchors.top: parent.verticalCenter
            spacing: 6
            Rectangle {
                 color: 'teal'
                 Layout.fillWidth: true
                 Layout.minimumWidth: 50
                 Layout.preferredWidth: 100
                 Layout.maximumWidth: 300
                 Layout.minimumHeight: 150
                 Text {
                      anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                      text: parent.width + 'x' + parent.height
                 }
           }
            Rectangle {
                 width: 80
                 height: 80
                 color: "#FF0000"
                 
            }

            Rectangle {
                  color: 'plum'
                  Layout.fillWidth: true
                  Layout.minimumWidth: 100
                  Layout.preferredWidth: 200
                  Layout.preferredHeight: 100
                  Text {
                        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                        text: parent.width + 'x' + parent.height
                   }
             }
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Your line `anchors.fill: parent` conflicts with setting `width` and `height` to 100.

Comment: it doesn't matter, the width and height are ignored when you use anchors.fill,  but if you leave the `width` and `height` as `0`,  then the QML engine considers it to not be a visual element, and therefore will not process any resizing events etc and often times will actually delete the item entirely from memory until it has a size greater than 0 as stated in the Qt Documentation

Comment: Yeah, I know Qt will ignore width and height there. I'm just saying it's confusing to people reading the code. I am perplexed that you say the Item would not process any resizing events without width and height being set, even though anchors.fill is set.

Comment: I didn't want the Item wrapper to fill the window because I have other children of WIndow that anchor to the top of the Item to fill the rest of the space unused by the thing(s) the Item contains.  So, I'm thinking I just need to eliminate Item and directly use the thing it contains (Rectangle in my original post, or RowLayout in my real code).

Comment: @Josh actually, don't eliminate any items, just add additional items as sub-items of the top level one and then put your code inside of the sub items.  This technique is called 'wrapping'  which is what they are referring to when talking about wrapping with `Item`

Comment: @JarMan Yes, I know it is perplexing, but if you read the documentation about how QtQuick renders the scenegraph, it specifically states that items with no height or width are deleted from the scenegraph's rendering engine, which is what handles the processing of visual elements. It has to do with the integration of the scene graph and the engine which are not 100% compatible or something

Comment: Do you have a link?

Comment: @JarMan also check out https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-visualcanvas-visualparent.html  and all linked documents to understand further

Comment: I could also read all of Google. You said, *"it specifically states that items with no height or width are deleted..."* You haven't provided anything that specifically states that. But the real point is in my experience I have never once needed to specify width and height when I use `anchors.fill: parent`.

Comment: Well, while this is true, the idea was to provide a working example where the OP's code would render properly, and the OP wanted to anchor to the bottom of the window, thereby using anchors.fill was required.  Have a look at https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmlapplications.html   if you are still confused.   I recommend reading the entire thing prior to writing QML code as it clears up a lot of confusion. @JarMan